# How can i keep my database clean between my scenarios?

Tags: django, bdd, django-testing, lettuce

I have two scenarios that create a record in a database. Let's say I'm creating a user with `foo@bar.com`.

- *Scenario 1:* Given I have an user with email `foo@bar.com`
- *Scenario 2:* Given I have an user with email `foo@bar.com`

*Scenario 2* is raising an error that says there is already a record with `foo@bar.com`. I think that I need to setup a hook to cleanup database between scenarios.

What is best practice for this stuation? Calling `flushdb` command between scenarios? Or transaction rollbacks? Or what else?

Comment: Flushdb is a good option. You want scenarios to be independent of one another and "end-to-end" to some extent so rebuild db for each one.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `get_or_create` method in both scenarios. Don't forget that `get_or_create` returns a tuple:

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> superman, created = User.objects.get_or_create(username='kal-el')
>>> superman
<User: kal-el>
>>> created
True
>>> superman_returns, created_again = User.objects.get_or_create(username='kal-el')
>>> superman_returns
<User: kal-el>
>>> created_again
False
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create